# Getting ECONNREFUSED error in nodejs when logstash server disconnects

Tags: node.js, tcp, logstash, bunyan

I am using [node-bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) and [bunyan-logstash-tcp](https://github.com/chris-rock/bunyan-logstash-tcp) in my nodejs application to send the logs to logstash (1.4.2) and elasticsearch (1.4.2).

Whenever the logstash server disconnects or is not reachable, my nodejs application crashes giving the following error

```
ERROR
-------
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

bunyan-logstash-tcp should actually handle this error. 
Can anyone please help me to solve this nodejs crashing issue.

Comment: You should look into closed issues, one seems to be similar to yours: https://github.com/chris-rock/bunyan-logstash-tcp/issues/5

Comment: @Val I have already given max_connect_retries: -1 and retry_interval: 1000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue.
Error event needs to be handled while creating tcp bunyan stream

```
stream: bunyantcp.createStream({
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 9998
    }).on('error', console.log)
```

This is not mentioned in the [bunyan-logstash-tcp](https://github.com/chris-rock/bunyan-logstash-tcp) documentation, but was there in an example code.

UPDATE: Sample configuration

```
this.log = bunyan.createLogger({
name: name,
streams: [
    {
      level: 'error', 
      type: 'raw',
      serializers: bunyan.stdSerializers,
      stream: bunyantcp.createStream({
          application: process.title,
          max_connect_retries: 10, // Don't give up on reconnecting
          retry_interval: 1000 * 60     // Wait 1s between reconnect attempts
      }).on('error', console.log)
    }
  ],
  level: 'debug'
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a more full example of your logging configuration?  I have same issue but capturing the error isn't preventing the crash.

Comment: @MrB I have updated my answer with sample configuration. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For logstash you could probably switch to UDP from TCP.
There are few important advantages:

- no connection issues (no reconnect problems, etc)
- less performance overhead
- less network overhead

Logentries' got a nice blogpost about it: https://blog.logentries.com/2014/07/tcp-or-udp-for-logging/

Take a look at some out-of-the box libs for logstash (elk stack) that support UDP: https://github.com/devmetrics/devmetrics-nodejs-core